# If Else statement giving an invalid syntax error on equal sign?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a simple if else statement that is giving me troubles, for some reason the equals sign is giving off an invalid syntax.

I've tried changing the = to an == but it wont give me the if statement but rather the else statement even though the input is corresponding to the if statement.

```
print("type in the corresponding number")
print("1")
print("2")
menuvar=int(input())
if menuvar = 1:
    print("good")
elif menuvar = 2:
    print("bad")
else:
    print('no')
```

I'm expecting the output to be good when i input 1 and bad when I input 2

Comment: for sure you have to use double `=`, in python for comparison it is always `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is just `==`

```py
print("type in the corresponding number")
print("1")
print("2")
menuvar=int(input())
if menuvar == 1:
    print("good")
elif menuvar == 2:
    print("bad")
else:
    print('no')
```

Is work for me https://repl.it/repls/ArcticDapperParameters